# Installed mysql from source on linux and then how to get it work with php?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I installed apache and php from source and got them working together a month ago. Because I'm learning both of them this term. 
Now I need mysql to do more works. And I installed mysql from source just now. However I don't know how to let it work with php.
I looked around and found some topics on setting up LAMP environment. Most of them install mysql first and use command options `--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql` and `--with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config` when installing php. But in my case, I installed php first.
Is there any way to let php know that I have installed mysql? Or should I reinstall php ?

#### UPDATE

Finally I recompiled my php source with appending `--with-mysql=/opt/mysql`, `--with-mysqli=/opt/mysql/bin/mysql_config` and `--with-pdo-mysql` three configure options to let my php support the modules of mysql. Steps taken as follows:
1> stop apache and mysql services 
2> backup php.ini 
3> remove php 
4> reconfigure php source
`./configure --prefix=/opt/php --with-apxs2=/opt/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysql=/opt/mysql --with-mysqli=/opt/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-pdo-mysql --...and other options` 
5> make and then make install 
6> copy php.ini back and uncomment the corresponding directs on mysql modules

Comment: @s.webbandit am using Ubuntu and CentOS, now testing on Ubuntu

Comment: Make sure you have uncommented mysql libraries in php.ini file and edit them properly. Restart apache and use `phpinfo()` to see if it is showing up mysql enabled.

Comment: @SumitMalik I uncommented mysql libraries in php.ini file and restarted apache. But I can't find keywords like 'mysql' on my phpinfo() page.

Comment: 1) uncomment ;extension_dir="ext"
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
2) make sure you have supplied correct directory path.

Comment: make sure you have installed `php-mysql`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you installing packages from source?

Use `yum` in CentOS and `apt-get` in Ubuntu like:

```
yum install php
yum install mysql
```

To make PHP work with MYSQL you have to install `php-mysql` extention like:

```
yum install php-mysql
```